# camera does not follow player after build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a situation here. i am making a car racing game on endless road. On the remote main camera works correctly but when i build the game the camera does not follow player car.
I shake the main camera when player car collides with big vehicle.
here the both scripts are:

camera follows player car Script:

```
GameObject cam ;
public GameObject[] Follow;
int i = CarSelectScript.playerCarIndex;
void Update()
{
    Follow [i].SetActive (true);
    Camera cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
    if (cam !=null) 
    {
        if (Follow[i]) 
        {
            cam.transform.position = new Vector3(Follow[i].transform.position.x -40.0f, cam.transform.position.y, cam.transform.position.z);    
        }
    }
}
```

here the camera shake Script is:

```
var startingShakeDistance : float = 0.8f;
var decreasePercentage : float = 0.5f;
var shakeSpeed : float = 50;
var numberOfShakes : int = 10;
var cam: Camera;
function CamerShake()
{


var hitTime : float = Time.time;
var OriginalPosition : float = cam.transform.localPosition.z;
var shake = numberOfShakes;
var shakeDistance : float = startingShakeDistance;

while(shake)
{
    var timer : float = (Time.time - hitTime) * shakeSpeed;
    cam.transform.localPosition.z = OriginalPosition + Mathf.Sin(timer) * hakeDistance;
    if(timer> Mathf.PI * 2)
    {
        hitTime = Time.time;
        shakeDistance *= decreasePercentage;
        shake--;
    }
    yield;
}
cam.transform.localPosition.z = OriginalPosition;
}
```

I do not understand why camera does not follow after i build the game install it in android device.

Comment: 1) Be patient. 2) Have you checked whether GetComponent<Camera>() returns null? 3) Have you checked whether Follow[i] is not null?

Comment: You should be getting errors, fix those first :/

Answer (score 0):

You have allot of general flaws in your code. You should try to fix those first

1. cam is defined twice ? once as GameObject and once as camera. Try only to use the camera one if you want the camera.
2. Camera cam = GetComponent(); runs in a update?! dont! , run it in a start function instead
3. Your get component has no camera to get his component off. Try using cam = [Camera.Main](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html) instead, if you only use 1 camera.
4. unless you are childing your camera some where else or running a 2d game the movement will not work, as it will only move over its X axis and maintain the current transform of the camera on both the Y and Z axis

Comment: that's what i want. I want camera follow the Follow[i] gameObject on X axis.

Comment: @DaniDanish Well the 4th point is okay then. But the other 3 still stand.

Comment: but this thing is not running on my cell phone and tab ... main camera does not follow the player car ... i am so fed up that i have just ruined my today :( @MX D

Comment: Just try to child your camera to the object you want to follow.